# How to separate values from form collection object with repeated separator value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I'm stuck with the string split functionality in my own project where the case scenario is as follows:

1) I have a `formCollection` object values which are passed when we send the page to server for manipulation purpose, where I have one field which is decimal with precision of 13 and scale of 2 and I have one JavaScript function which call on `onblur event` of `textbox` which return the Input values in currency formatted value. 
for eg  "12500" in "12,500.00" or 130000 in "1,30,000.00"

2) But the thing is that I'm separating the formCollection values by ',' but in this case it is separating the value  like:

eg "12,500.00" in "12"

I want the separation from '.00'

My Development Platform is ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

Comment: Looks like you should split on `'.'`, not `','`

Comment: you better explain with your code. can't you change the formCollection  value delimiter to something like `||`?

Comment: yes i also thinking to implement this way but this is the formCollection varibale ?? can we chage the behaviour of FormCollection values separator...

Comment: See this is what we are getting the formCollection values after postback is string Variable = "13,23,4469.00;785845,00,988655.00" and its an array so how to implement the spliting functionality with '.00'

Comment: if i split with '.' then the ',' character will be added to next split and it will throw the casting error while insertion of records in Database

Comment: Can we see the code of your controller. The problem may be there.

Comment: hmmm hi Professionls i got the solution                                                               form["PersonRate[]"] = form["PersonRate[]"].ToString().Replace(",", "").Trim();
                string[] PersonRate = form["PersonRate[]"].Split(new string [] {".00"},StringSplitOptions.None);
                                //End

Comment: Now the Value is seperated from '.00' not from ','

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the .GetString method?

If I am not mistaken a Formcollection is a namevalue collection. You should be able to get each one by looping through it. For example:

```
 foreach (var key in formValues.Keys)
 {
     object value = formValues[key.ToString()];
 }
```

Where in that case `formvalues` is your formCollection

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method.
For more information please go to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Code example:

```
var example= "12,500.00";
var split= example.Split('.')[0];
```

This will give you 12,500

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y6O1Zg)